# Quick way to clone a production RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS Instance which is currently in production and all the apps are using the same RDS instance. Now when I want to make separate RDS instances for each app, I tried using RDS feature called restore to point in time but it took nearly one hour to create a new RDS instance.

Can someone suggest me some good way to perform it so that i can create an exact replica  of running rds instance.

Comment: Are you using high-availability (multi-AZ) RDS instances? To you just need a read replica or will you need to write to it?  If you need to write to it, are you looking for a true replicated set-up (i.e. master-master replica)?

Comment: @MikeBrant: We dont need to write, so it was also thinking of creating a read replica and using it.

Comment: AWS Documentations: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html

Comment: @Guy: I tested out the read replica method in one staging rds instance. It took nearly 10 minutes for promoting a read replica to separate db instance and to convert that db instance to multi-az, it again took nearly 8 minutes. These are going to add to my downtime. Is there any other better way ?

Comment: @pradeepchhetri, you don't need to stop your instance for the replication. Depends on the size of your data, there is a short (few seconds up to a minute) I/O suspension for the snapshot of the data.

Comment: @Guy: Ya I understood to create a read replica, it took snapshot of source rds instance but what I didnt understand is why it took nearly 10 minutes for promoting a read replica to separate db instance.

Comment: RDS is mainly a managed service of the existing DB engine. Most of the time that you are waiting is around the native calls to the engine.

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider using Aurora Mysql as opposed to RDS Mysql fr the clone use case. You can spin up a clone in a matter of minutes, and it does not even duplicate your database pages unless you mutate them (copy on write protocol).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html

Restoring snapshots are definitely not going to be as fast as cloning as they incur data copying over head. If you need to continue using RDS, then yes, having a hot replica stand-by is the best bet, although I'm not entirely convinced that that's what you're looking for.